# Correct way to find vpn gateway using script

Tags: vpn, iproute, ifconfig

I need to find ip that my vpn interface (`vpn0`) uses to connect so I can setup routes correctly using a script.

What is correct way to do this?

First solution I tried

```
❯ ip r | sed -rn "s/.*dev vpn0 proto kernel scope link src ([0-9.]+) .*/\1/p"
10.8.231.186
```

But this didn't work on both machines because `ip r` returns

```
10.8.224.0/20 dev vpn0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.231.186 metric 50
```

for one one of them and

```
10.8.224.0/20 dev vpn0 scope link
```

for the another.

Two other solutions that I tried:

```
❯ ip a s dev vpn0 | sed -rn 's/.*inet (([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+).*/\1/p'
10.8.231.186

❯ ifconfig vpn0 | sed -rn "s/.*destination ([0-9.]+)/\1/p"
10.8.231.186
```

How should I do this?

*edit* (this is what I have currently)

```
get-endpoint() {
  if hash jq 2>/dev/null; then
    ip -4 -j a | jq -r ".[] | select(.ifname == \"${1}\").addr_info[0].local"
  else
    ip -4 a s dev "${1}" | sed -rn 's/.*inet (([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+).*/\1/p'
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the GNU `grep` that supports PCRE you could use something like this

```
ip r | grep -oP ' vpn0 .* src \K[0-9.]+'
```

The `\K` separates a "must match but don't show" criterion with a "show this match" pattern.

Worked example

```
printf "%s\n%s\n" '10.8.224.0/20 dev vpn0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.231.186 metric 50' '10.8.224.0/20 dev vpn0 scope link' |
    grep -oP ' vpn0 .* src \K[0-9.]+'

10.8.231.186
```

---

Alternatively, since I'm not at all sure why you're looking at `ip route` to find interface addresses, use `ip address` and parse that

```
ip a |
    awk -v netif='vpn0' '
        $2 == netif ":" { this=1 }
        this && $1 == "inet" { gsub("/[[:digit:]]+", "", $2); print $2; exit }
    '
```

Or, as one line

```
ip a | awk -v netif='vpn0' '$2==netif":" {this=1} this && $1=="inet" {gsub("/[[:digit:]]+","",$2); print $2; exit}'
```

Yet another option is to parse the JSON that `ip` can provide (probably the better option for a script, assuming you have `jq`)

```
ip -j address |
    jq -r '.[] | select(.ifname | contains("vpn0")) | .addr_info[0].local'
```

Comment: Problem isn't with parsing (`grep`,`sed`,`awk`,etc). As I said above `ip r` didn't work because second machine didn't print any `src`, only `10.8.224.0/20 dev vpn0 scope link`

Comment: The second one isn't an IP address - is that your issue? It wasn't clear in your question. If you actually want IP addresses why not look at `ip address`? I'll update the answer

Comment: I was setting routes and `ip r` did return src ip in some scenarios, so I kinda got mentally stuck on that. I combined your json option with `ip -4 a s dev vpn0` parsed with sed for now.